# Combine two PDF-a documents using ITextSharp

Tags: merge, itext, pdfa

hoping that someone can see the flaw in my code to merge to PDF-a documents using ITextSharp. Currently it complains about missing metadata which PDF-a requires.

```
Document document = new Document();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
using (PdfACopy pdfaCopy = new PdfACopy(document, ms, PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_1A))
{
    document.Open();
    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("Doc1.pdf"))
    {
        pdfaCopy.AddDocument(reader);
    }
    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("doc2.pdf"))
    {
        pdfaCopy.AddDocument(reader);
    }
}
```

The exact error received is

Unhandled Exception: iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfAConformanceException: The document catalog dictionary of a PDF/A conforming file shall contain
the Metadata key

I was hoping that the 'document catalog dictionary' would be copied as well, but I guess the 'new Document()' creates an empty non-conforming document or something.

Thanks! Hope you can help

Wouter

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this line:

```
copy.CreateXmpMetadata();
```

This will create some default XMP metadata. Of course: if you want to create your own XMP file containing info about the documents you're about to merge, you can also use:

```
copy.XmpMetadata = myMetaData;
```

where `myMetaData` is a byte array containing a correct XMP stream.

I hope you understand that iText can't automatically create the correct metadata. Providing metadata is something that needs human attention.

Comment: When do we should call this ? Before some special action, or on the contrary afterwards ? or it doesn't matter? (assuming it's only for pdfa- related metadata)